# PHP DateTime : get current week/month/year interval (start-end) compared with the previous year

Tags: php, datetime, comparison

> Today is 2015-05-22 (to understand the example)

I have to see some statistics taking values from a database. Initially I had to do these comparisons

- this week compared with the previous week. [**2015-05-18 00:00:00** # **2015-05-24 23:59:59**] - [**2015-05-11 00:00:00** # **2015-05-17 00:00:00**]
- this month compared with the previous month. [**2015-05-01 00:00:00** # **2015-05-31 23:59:59**] - [**2015-04-01 00:00:00** # **2015-04-30 23:59:59**]
- this year compared with the previous year. [**2015-01-01 00:00:00** # **2015-12-31 23:59:59**] -  [**2014-01-01 00:00:00** # **2014-12-31 23:59:59**]

For all these controls i do this function that calculated all the various date intervals.

```
function getIntervalDate(){

    $today = new DateTime();
    $appToday = new DateTime();

    $numDay = date("w");
    $numYear = (int)date("Y");

    switch($numDay){
        //monday
        case 1 : 
            $startWeek = $today->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
            $endWeek = $today->modify('next sunday')->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');

            $startWeek2 = $today->modify('last monday -1 week')->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
            $endWeek2 = $today->modify('next sunday')->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');

        break;
        default:
            $startWeek = $today->modify('last monday')->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
            $endWeek = $today->modify('next sunday')->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');

            $startWeek2 = $today->modify('last monday -1 week')->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
            $endWeek2 = $today->modify('next sunday')->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');

        break;
    }

    $startMonth = $today->modify('first day of this month')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $endMonth = $today->modify('last day of this month')->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');

    $today1 = $appToday;

    $startMonth2 = $today1->modify('first day of previous month')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $endMonth2 = $today1->modify('last day of this month')->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');

    $today2 = $appToday;

    $startYear = $today2->modify('first day of January '.$numYear)->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
    $endYear = $today2->modify('last day of December '.$numYear)->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');

    $today3 = $appToday;

    $startYear2 = $today3->modify('first day of January '.($numYear-1))->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
    $endYear2 = $today3->modify('last day of December '.($numYear-1))->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');

    return array(

        "startWeek" => $startWeek,
        "endWeek" => $endWeek,
        "startWeek2" => $startWeek2,
        "endWeek2" => $endWeek2,

        "startMonth" => $startMonth,
        "endMonth" => $endMonth,
        "startMonth2" => $startMonth2,
        "endMonth2" => $endMonth2,

        "startYear" => $startYear,
        "endYear" => $endYear,
        "startYear2" => $startYear2,
        "endYear2" => $endYear2

    );

}
```

[image]

Everything works perfectly. But now i have to change the various comparisons. I have to always compare the current **week / month / year** interval but with the week / month / year in the previous year (in the case of the year there are no problems, the code remains the same)

I did some tests but i failed. I used mostly the `->modify('-1 year')` but with not a perfect result.

Comment: Glad to see someone actually use DateTime instead of mangling strtotime() and date()

Comment: "but with not a perfect result." Care to elaborate on what went wrong?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Heru-Luin "I have to always compare the week / month / year interval but with the week / month / year in the previous year"

Comment: @MariM , for example the current week (start) but in the previous year. i get 2014-05-18 and not 2014-05-19

Comment: So do you mean you are not getting the correct previous year or day?

Comment: so if you have e.g.  `$startWeek=new DateTime("2015-05-18 00:00:00")->modify('-1 year');` it returns `2014-05-18 00:00:00` which *is* 1 year previous. Sounds like you really want it to return `2014-05-19 00:00:00` because that's the start of week (monday) for the week it falls on.  Well that's not going to make it exactly one year prior.  But to do that, you'd have to modify for `-1 year` and then also do the same thing you did in your `switch`

Comment: @CrayonViolent the goal is just that

Comment: okay so.. what's the problem then? you've already got the code. Just take the `-1 year` modified date and run it through the `switch`.

Comment: $appToday = new DateTime('-1 year');

Comment: @CrayonViolent I try now!

Comment: @WhiteLine: please check my answer based on your discussion above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your discussion above here is the solution of your problem:

`$startWeek->modify("-1 year")->modify('monday')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Here is the test.

```
$today = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-05-18 00:00:00');
$startWeekPrevYear=$today->modify('-1 year')->modify('monday');

echo $startWeekPrevYear->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');//outputs 2014-05-19 00:00:00
```

Comment: It's up-to you but main purpose behind the answer was logic if it has helped please accept it.